# Active Directory Search query buid

Tags: filter, active-directory

I am trying to find a list of users that are DISABLED ( no locked )

This users must have a home folder mapped and the folder starts with `\\userdatasrv\`

I manged to find the custom filter for the home folder:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(homeDirectory=\5c\5cuserdatasrv*))
```

also I found some examples for disabled users on the internet but I can't make them work together.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a search filter that looks something like this:

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(homeDirectory=\5c\5cuserdatasrv*))`

Also remember to use objectCategory person. The objectCategory for a user object is not user it is person and objectClass is not enough since computer class is a sublclass of user. objectCategory will give you both user objects and contact objects.

This will only include accounts that are disabled. For more information about using bitwise filters see this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269181